# What are these "media information" and "usage rights" windows media player is downloading?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-media-player

I was wondering what does "media information" and "usage rights" mean in the first three textboxes.

[image]

I was under the impression that "music files" are my MP3 files so what does it mean to *update* my music files by retrieving information from the Internet?

Also, since these files are "*offline* MP3 files" how could they display the media information of these files from the internet ?

Comment: What does help say about them when you click the "More information about these privacy options" link in that window? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Media Information is track names, artists, etc.  It applies to CD tracks which have a serial number identifying the CD.  Most CD's don't come with track and artist information included, so this information is downloaded from a central database.  Unless your MP3s contain information on which CD they came from, they will be ignored.

Usage Rights applies to music bought from an online store.  Since your MP3s were sourced elsewhere, they don't have any encryption requiring these usage rights.  Windows Media Player will ignore your MP3 files.

Basically, leaving any of these options on or off isn't going to change your experience.

Comment: how do I check if my MP3 file contain this "information" on which CD it came from?

Comment: It'll show up under the File Properties.

Comment: Not sure, probably with an ID3 tag viewer.  It might not even be an option on MP3 files.  I know I've seen it on some other ancient format back in the days of Windows 3.

Comment: @surfasb do you mean the "part of set": http://i.imgur.com/cfUFV.jpg